# ¿Como puedo escribir en un archivo con multiples lineas en java?

Tags: java, archivo

Tengo un método que genera 10000 numeros y los almaceno en un arreglo.

Quisiera que dichos datos se escriban en un archivo de 10 lineas con 1000 numeros por linea.

Esto es lo que he intentado:

```
try {
        File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/datos.txt");//crea el archivo txt
        BufferedWriter bw;
        if (f.exists()) {
            bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));//se encargara de escribir en el txt
            for (int i = 0; i < lista.getLongitud(); i++) {
                bw.write((Integer) lista.obtenerNodo(i) + ",");//escribe los datos en el txt
            }
        bw.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {//si falla mandara el error generado
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error en IO"+ ex.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
```

Comment: ¿Simplemente quieres que cada 1000 renglones haya un enter?

Comment: ¿Que se escriban los datos en filas de 1000 datos?  ¿Eso qué significa exactamente?

Comment: 1000 palabras serian?

Comment: lo siento mala redaccion. que escriba 10 filas de 1000 datos cada una

Comment: Pero... ¿cuando hablas de *1000 datos*  a qué te refieres? Ya que es lo que quieres separar, deberías decir qué son esos mil datos (1000 palabras, 1000 líneas, 1000 frases...)?

Comment: numeros separados por una coma, cuando llegue a los 1000 numeros haga un salto de linea

Comment: es todo solo una mala calificacion crei que era para ayudar a los principiantes y personas con dudas o mejor dicho crei que tu eras asi

Comment: Con tus comentarios queda claro, sería bueno que editaras tu pregunta aclarando que se trata de 10 filas de 1000 numeros cada una.

Answer (score 1):

Guíandome por tu descripcion en los comentarios:

> numeros separados por una coma, cuando llegue a los 1000 numeros haga
>   un salto de linea
>
> que escriba 10 filas de 1000 datos cada una

En el siguiente código se crea un listado de diez mil números, los cuales se grabaran en el archivo en lineas de a 1000 números.

En cada iteración se crea un bloque el cual se va a bajar al archivo. Este bloque es la concatenación de 1000 números separados por coma, creado a partir de una sublista de la lista original.

Cada vez que se completen 1000 números se comienza a escribir una línea nueva mediante `bw.writeLine()`

```
public static void main(String[] args)   {
         // Test raw data
         List<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>();
         for(int i =1; i<=10000; i++) {
             numbers.add(""+i);
         }

         // File creation
         File f = new File("data.txt");
         if(!f.exists()) {
             try {
                f.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }

         // File writing
         try( FileWriter fr = new FileWriter(f);
                 BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fr)){

             List<String> block = new ArrayList<String>();
             for(int i =0; i<numbers.size(); i+=1000) {
                 // writes a block with 1000 elements and creates a new line
                 block = numbers.subList(i, i+1000);
                 bw.write(String.join(",", block));
                 bw.newLine();
              }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: que es el newline????

Comment: La escritura de una nueva línea, agrega el caracter de separación de linea, como puede ser \n. [BufferedReader.newLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#newLine())